# Making an absolutely positioned div container match the width of its contents

Tags: html, css, slider, css-float

I have a CSS setup where I have an PNG image, absolutely positioned, with a transparent area that acts as sort of a window for a div full of images to show through behind it. That div is absolutely positioned as well, and its contents are a series of images floated left so that they are all in a single line.

The problem is that this div full of images is much wider than the container, so unless I specify a width for the image container div, the images all just stack up vertically. I want them to line up side by side, but I can't hard code a value for the width of the containing div, because it can change. How do I do this? Here's my code:

```
<div class="slider_box">
    <div class="slider_images">
        <img class="slider_image" src="img/share/recipes/pizza.jpg" alt="Pizza"/>
        <img class="slider_image" src="img/share/recipes/pizza.jpg" alt="Pizza"/>
        <img class="slider_image" src="img/share/recipes/pizza.jpg" alt="Pizza"/>
        <img class="slider_image" src="img/share/recipes/pizza.jpg" alt="Pizza"/>
        <img class="slider_image" src="img/share/recipes/pizza.jpg" alt="Pizza"/>
    </div> <!--images show through the slider mask, and should be floated left (or inline-block). Currently can't be side by side without specifying width of slider_images-->
    <img class="slider_mask" alt="Slider Mask" src="img/share_recipe_mask.png"/><!--sits on top of slider images -->
    <h4>Semolina <br/>Olive Oil Cake</h4> <!--sits on top of slider mask-->
</div>

.slider_box {
    width:190px; height:220px; position: absolute; overflow: hidden;
    .slider_images {
        position: absolute; bottom: 0;
        img { float: none; width: 190px; height:158px; }
    }
    .slider_mask { position: absolute; }
    h4 { .cubano; font-size:1.8em; position: absolute; color: #fff; top:11px; left:14px; line-height: 110%; }
}
```

CSS

```
.slider_box {
    width:190px; height:220px; position: absolute; overflow: hidden;
    .slider_images {
        position: absolute; bottom: 0;
        img { float: none; width: 190px; height:158px; }
    }
    .slider_mask { position: absolute; }
    h4 { .cubano; font-size:1.8em; position: absolute; color: #fff; top:11px; left:14px; line-height: 110%; }
}
.slider_nav {
    .slider_nav_btn { width:10px; height:10px; display:inline-block; .border-radius(50%,50%,50%,50%); color: #f3895f; }
    .slider_nav_btn:hover { color: @redDk; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I grasp the situation correctly, you need the container to be the size of the mask, right?

With a little Javascript:

```
<div class="slider_box" id="easyID">
<!-- snip -->
<img class="slider_mask" id="easytoidentify" src="whatever" />
<script type="text/javascript">
  document.getElementById('easyID').style.width = document.getElementById('easytoidentify').width;
</script>
```

From there, you just need to add `overflow:hidden` to the "slider_box" css and define the width of "slider_images" so that it's wide enough. As long as Javascript is enabled at all, this works.

Comment: container needs to be the size of the images it contains, and I'm trying to do it without javascript.

Comment: When you say "the size of the images it contains," what exactly do you mean? Are "slider_image" images a different size than "slider_mask"? Do you want the container to be big enough to fit all of the "slider_image"s side by side? Please be clear.

Comment: Also, are you serving these pages as static HTML or are you using a server-side scripting language?